# How to get a new list by exchanging some elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, group-theory

Let's begin with a simple example. Now, we have a list,

```
list0=Range[4];
```

k1 and k2 are some elements of the list0. If |k1-k2|==2, then
the elements k1 and k2 can interchange their positions.(Namely, 1 and 3 can echange; 2 and 4 can exchange) 
With this condition, we can get a new list including 4 elements,

```
listnew={{1,2,3,4},{3,2,1,4},{1,4,3,2},{3,4,1,2}};
```

In the listnew, the no-exchange list0 is also included. And the sequence of the elements in the listnew are not important.

My problem is,  if we consider,

```
 list0=Range[16];
```

and the exchange condition is,

```
|k1-k1|==4 Or |k1-k1|==8 Or |k1-k1|==12
```

How to get the listnew by using a general and simple way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for 16 elements too:

```
list0 = Range[4];

sep = 2; (* separation of exchangeable elements *)

exchangeable = 
 Select[Subsets[list0, {2}], Abs[Subtract @@ #] == sep &]
(* {{1, 3}, {2, 4}} *)

group = PermutationGroup[Cycles[{#}] & /@ exchangeable]
(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}]}] *)

elements = GroupElements[group]
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]} *)

listnew = PermutationList[#, Length[list0]] & /@ elements
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}} *)
```

Be sure to add semicolons to suppress output when trying it for 16 elements.

Comment: Thanks. This is just what I want to get.